# Fixed width element with variable width input

Tags: html, css, variable-width

Your probably going to say this has been asked before but this is a variation with a bug. So we are all aware of the technique used to answer this question:
[Fixed width div on left, fill remaining width div on right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724967/fixed-width-div-on-left-fill-remaining-width-div-on-right)

However this does not work if the variable width element is an input tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/8pk4K/2050/

even overriding the inputs default css doesnt fix this:

```
display: block;
overflow:hidden; 
background-color:green;
height: 100px;
width: auto;
```

Iv been playing with this for ages, it only happens on input tags, if you replace it with a span (default display inline but set it to display block) it still works.

Any idea why this only **doesnt** work for input tags and nothing else?

EDIT:
For clarification, I know that the fix for this is to put the input into a div and apply width 100% to the input. My question is why this is necessary, not how to fix it.

Comment: You can use calc to produce what you desire    width: calc(100% - 240px);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use calc to produce the width what you desire because inputs are replaced elements that have intrinsic dimensions just like images

**CSS**

```
.header-right{
    display: block;
    overflow:hidden; 
    background-color:green;
    height: 100px;
    border: none;
    width: calc(100% - 240px); //Add this
    }
```

**Note:** You must give a dimension (width) to the select or otherwise give you the default browser width

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/8pk4K/2061/)**

Comment: Mind the browser support, since it's an experimental technology... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @ LinkinTED Just check - http://caniuse.com/#search=calc   ... I think that most modern browser support it. It´s safe.

Comment: P.A.: at least all the latest version do (except Opera Mini), and imo you should always keep your software updated... so I'm with you on this one!

Comment: this is a nice fix, however i am not after a fix, I am just curious why input does not behave in the expected manor

Comment: @MikeOram, Inputs are replaced elements have intrinsic dimensions just like images..I add a note in my answer

Comment: can you elaborate on this? add it as an answer so I can accept it (as you have actually answered the question lol)

Comment: what do you mean by intrinsic dimensions?

Comment: So..it´s simple...you must give a dimension (width) to the select or otherwise give you the default browser width.

Comment: but surely applying width: auto should override the browser default and so fill the space. or does auto just inherit the browser default?

Comment: input will not recognize with:auto, its not a real dimension..because of that when we put width:auto we got the default dimension

Answer (score 2):

I know the problem, styling form elements will always be a pain in the ass.

I've came up with this work around, by wrapping the input in the right div.

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="header-right">
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

```
.header{
    float:left;
    background: #efefef;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 240px;
    height: 100px;
    }

.header-right{
    overflow:hidden; 
    background-color:#000;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    }
.header-right input {
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8pk4K/2060/)

Comment: thanks, I actually already know the fix for this I just dont understand why this is necessary

Answer (score -1):

Try adding width in % for both .header and .header-right.
Like

```
.header{
width:20%;
}
.header-right{
width:80%;
}
```

Comment: this is neither what i asked or the solution